# Post Order Traversal Formula

Tags: data-structures, tree, tree-traversal

I am given `2 y 5 1 4 3 - * - * +`, and am asked to evaluate it, and then draw the equivalent expression tree. I haven't done any work with this before, can someone show the steps you would take to solve this type of question?

I have looked at: [Post order traversal of a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929428/post-order-traversal-of-a-formula)
and am confused as to how to come to that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are given is a postfix expression.  It is well-known that these things are evaluated with stacks according to the following rule:

> Working left to right, when you encounter a value, push it.  When you encounter an operator, pop the top two values, apply the operation, and push the result back.

So your expression evaluation proceeds like this

```
2               (push 2)
2 y             (push y)
2 y 5           (push 5)
2 y 5 1         (push 1)
2 y 5 1 4       (push 4)
2 y 5 1 4 3     (push 3)
2 y 5 1 1       (pop 3, pop 4, push 4-3)
2 y 5 1         (pop 1, pop 1, push 1*1)
2 y 4           (pop 1, pop 5, push 5-1)
2 4y            (pop 4, pop y, push y*4)
2+4y            (pop 4y, pop 2, push 2+4y)
```

Your answer is the value left on the stack.

Now, you asked about *producing a tree* also.  To produce a tree, rather than evaluating the expression when you find an operator, you "apply" the operator by building a tree fragment with the operator as the root, and the popped tree fragments as children.

So after pushing

```
2 y 5 1 4 3
```

you see a `-`, so you pop the 4 and 3 and you push back this structure

```
  -
 / \
4   3
```

Next you see the `*` so you pop the top tree fragment and the one below it, which is actually a tree fragment consisting of the single node

```
1
```

So it will look like

```
   *
 /   \
1     -
     / \
    4   3
```

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Would this be the correct answer for the diagram? http://gyazo.com/00a749ac53f9674850abb698035c34dc.png

Answer (score 1):

The answer at [Post order traversal of a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929428/post-order-traversal-of-a-formula) says find the first operator. In your case it is '-'. The second step he describes is put it between the previous two operands.
In your case these two operands are 4 and 3 (they are directly before the '-'). So the formula after this step becomes:

```
2 y 5 1 (4-3) * - * +
```

Remember that the expression (4-3) is now one operand.

We apply the steps again to this formula. We see that the first operator now is '*'.
The two operands before the '*' are 1 and (4-3). The formula becomes:

```
2 y 5 (1*(4-3)) - * +
```

Now you can apply this untill all operators are gone.

I will not continue giving more steps because probably this is a homework question. However I think it is clear?

Comment: One follow up question would be, what is the procedure for a pre-ordered traversal, and in-order traversal?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by novalis from the question you linked, scan for the first operator and previous 2 operands and then replace that group with a more familiar expression in parentheses, ie.

if you have:

```
op1 op2 operator
4    3     -
```

this becomes:

```
(op1 operator op2)
(4      -      3 )
```

so, proceeding...

```
2  y  5  1  4  3 -  *  -  *  +

2  y  5  1 (4 - 3)  *  -  *  +

2  y  5  (1 * (4 - 3)) -  *  +
```

Proceed in a similar fashion to build the tree. Scan for the first operator and create a tiny tree:

```
  -
 / \
4   3
```

Then, each new operand is the top node of your new tree:

```
   *
 /   \
1     -
     / \
    4   3
```

and then:

```
   -
  / \
 5   *
    / \
   1   -
      / \
     4   3
```